# Can't create Workbook

Tags: r, xlsx

failed to use package 'xlsx' to createWorkbook()

R--3.4.4 Windows 7

```
wb<-createWorkbook()

Error in .jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook") : 
  Java Exception 
(no description because toString() failed).jnew("org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook")<S4 object of class "jobjRef">
```

Comment: Do you get the same problem with absolute paths?

Comment: I tend to shy away from java-based R packages (heavily because I do not want Java installed on my machine, partly b/c troubleshooting `rJava`- or java-based errors is not my strength). You might consider using [`openxlsx`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html) instead of `xlsx`.